# Can I do dom manipulation on HTML loaded by an external script?

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-manipulation, external-script

I have a widget on a site that is loaded externally with a third-party `<script>`.

I need to manipulate DOM in their widget. Is there any way I can do this without a callback in their external script?

Comment: Once the HTML has been loaded into the DOM, it doesn't matter where it came from. You manipulate it the same way.

Comment: Are you asking how to know when the widget has made its DOM modifications, so you can do your own manipulations on the result? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3219758/detect-changes-in-the-dom

Comment: @Barmar I suppose so. When I just try to manipulate widget's HTML, nothing works.

Comment: If you provide a link to the widget and its documentation, someone may be able to find a specific solution for you.

Comment: @Barmar sadly its a commercial provider with no documentation and no public codebase.

Comment: In that case I hope they provide technical support and can help with a way to tailor the product to your needs.

Comment: @Barmar thanks for your feedback. I just needed setinterval to check whether widget existed in the DOM first, and only then do DOM manipulation.

Comment: That's a kludgey way to do it, but it will work. `MutationObserver` is a more direct way, but a little more complicated.